# How can I limit connections, including idle connections, to a PG database?

Tags: postgresql

psql (11.5, server 11.3) on linux.  (Yes, I know its an old version but IT is dragging it's heels on an upgrade)

I have a DB instance with 2 DBs, call then "Moe" and "Curley".  Max connections to the instance was set at 250.  I want to limit "Moe" to 50. I had the db admin issue.. ."ALTER DATABASE Moe CONNECTION LIMIT 50;" That appears to have stuck when looking at datconnlimit in pg_database.  And I also had them kill all the "idle" connections to "Moe".  The number of connections left was 8. But now, when I look at connections in pg_stat_activity, I see that "Moe" has 97, almost all are "idle".

I don't believe the DB instance was restarted after the "ALTER DATABASE...".  But I can't find anything in the documentation that says it's necessary.  Is a DB restart indeed needed?  Is there some other explanation as to why the DB conn limit is > 50 ?

Thanks in Advance for any help !

Comment: Pretty sure you will need to restart the server.

Comment: From the manual: `This parameter can only be set at server start.` So Yes, you have to restart the database server

Answer (score 2):

For a database-specific connection limit (unlike the cluster-wide one) no restart is needed.  But a superuser is not subject to the database-specific connection limit (again, unlike the cluster-wide one).  And that is the only plausible explanation I see, that the connections are as a superuser.